# ClickHouse left join between

Tags: left-join, clickhouse

I have two queries:

- The first one I have datetime of payment
- In the second one I have several sessions

I need to "left joint t2 on t1.datetime between t2.startDatetime and t2.endDatetime" to keep only one row which meet "between" statement

I know it works with SQL, but I can't find any information about same feature in ClickHouse.

Comment: "All standard SQL JOIN types are supported" so how are you stuck & why can't  the manual or SO SQL Qs&As answer your question? What are you able to do? Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]

Comment: Code: 403, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Invalid expression for JOIN ON. Expected equals expression, got (EventTime >= OnlineTime) AND (EventTime <= OfflineTime). Supported syntax: JOIN ON Expr([table.]column, ...) = Expr([table.]column, ...) [AND Expr([table.]column, ...) = Expr([table.]column, ...) ...] (version 19.9.5.36 (official build))

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. And that is clearly not a [mre].

Comment: CH supports only equi join (because it supports only HASHJOIN). An equijoin is a join with a join condition containing an equality operator. You can use cartesian join or rangeHashed dictionary in some special cases.

Comment: [ClickHouse Release 18.6.0, 2018-08-02](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/whats-new/changelog/2018/) Added support for ON expressions for the JOIN ON syntax:
`JOIN ON Expr([table.]column ...) = Expr([table.]column, ...) [AND Expr([table.]column, ...) = Expr([table.]column, ...) ...]` The expression must be a chain of equalities joined by the AND operator. Each side of the equality can be an arbitrary expression over the columns of one of the tables." For inequalities see [ASOF JOIN](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/join/).