# Clickhouse correlated queries/joins with multiple inequalities

Tags: database, join, left-join, clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I have this query I am trying to join 2 table based on 4 conditions

```
select 
* 
from table1 t1 
asof left join table2 t2 on t1.start=t2.start and t1.end=t2.end and (t1.spending between t2.spending-10 and t2.spending+10) and (t1.timestamp_ between subtractSeconds(t2.timestamp_, 10) and addSeconds(t2.timestamp_, 10))

t2.id in ('623d9d7ce62af3465dadf31f')) 
where  t1.id in ('623d9d86e62af3465dadf327')
SETTINGS join_use_nulls = 1
```

My conditions are:

- t1.start=t2.start
- t1.end=t2.end
- t1.spending between t2.spending - 10 and t2.spending + 10
- t1.timestamp_ between subtractSeconds(t2.timestamp_, 10) and addSeconds(t2.timestamp_, 10)

I am trying to join them but clickhouse only supports one **inequality condition**. I cannot use **subqueries** because I have to correlate the data and clickhouse does not support **correlated queries**. I have tried another query using **with clause** and **has** but has is also not supported. I have seen **dictionaries** but according to my understanding we have to define these things in dictionaries but i cant because my last two conditions **i.e iii,iv are generated dynamically**

I have seen these links but i wasnt able to solve my issue

- https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/3627
- https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/join/
- [clickhouse : left join using IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65722294/clickhouse-left-join-using-in)
- https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/5736
- https://ittone.ma/ittone/clickhouse-asof-join-with-multiple-inequalities/
- [ClickHouse left join between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62516932/clickhouse-left-join-between)
- [Get retention analytics: ASOF JOIN with multiple inequalities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66594746/get-retention-analytics-asof-join-with-multiple-inequalities)

Can someone pls tell me how to run this query. Any help would be appreciated

thanks